# Codeigniter Paypal notify url

Tags: codeigniter, paypal

I'm using paypal on a site based on Codeigniter. I set up the paypal form, everything is working fine except the notify_url. It's not called at all. The url is like this:
www.mysite.com/callback
If I change the url to a simple php file like www.mysite.com/callback.php, which is not part of the codeigniter framework, it's working fine.
I tested the original callback with the IPN simulator and it's working as well.
The first line of the callback is a logging function for testing but nothing happens.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you got any solution? please share it with all :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="<?=base_url()?>index.php/payment/prepaynotify">
```

Answer (score 0):

Check in your controller, there is any redirection or checking session for login. If any remove that. If you cannot remove purpose of checking session. Then you should put separate controller for PayPal notify url.

Hopes it will help